# Asp.net mvc web api security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have some ASP.NET MVC Web API Restful services, which will be consumed by some third party applications. I would like to know the best practices to build security around this communication. Should every call coming from the third party needs to authenticate, or can there be a token that can keeps the future communications from this third party alive for next xx minutes?

Note: I have an external IDMaaS solution provider for authentcation. I would like the incoming service calls to get authenticated against this IDP.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap tha whole app in Owin middleware and use Jwt to authenticate to IDMaas.  You're clients can then use the bearer token to authorise themselves every request.  Have a look at this on how to set it up:

http://dotnetcodr.com/2015/07/02/building-a-web-api-2-project-from-scratch-using-owinkatana-net-part-1/